# magento event observer (magento1.7)

Tags: module, magento-1.7

i am trying to implement an simple observer in my module (app/code/local/Foo/Bar).
My objective is to set the product names to '[product name] is cool' when a product is loaded in the frontend.

These are my files: 
**app/code/local/Foo/Bar/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <foo_bar>       
                    <class>Foo_Bar_Model</class>
            </foo_bar>  
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <foo_bar>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>foo_bar/observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductLoadAfter</method>
                    </foo_bar>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_load_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Foo/Bar/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php 
class Foo_Bar_Model_Observer{

public function catalogProductLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

{
    $product = $observer ->getProduct();

    $product ->setName($product.getName().' '.'is cool');
} 
}
?>
```

And i have also configured the module in **app/etc/modules/Foo_Bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
   <modules>
     <Foo_Bar>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
     </Foo_Bar>
  </modules>
</config>
```

But it doenst work, does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Shouldn't `$product.getName()` be `$product->getName()`?

Comment: Thank you so much @JürgenThelen! this took me like two hours, I still think like a Java developer :). Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to module name for the model:

```
<foo_bar>
     <type>model</type>
     <class>bar/observer</class>
     <method>catalogProductLoadAfter</method>
</foo_bar>
```

you don't need to specify Foo_Bar

also have you an error in your PHP

```
$product ->setName($product.getName().' '.'is cool');
```

should be

```
$product->setName($product->getName().' '.'is cool');
```